# Adding an Embedded Chart to word document using open xml

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

The word document contains Embedded chart, i want copy and paste same chart int the other document using open xml. I have used Following code but file is being corrupt after pasting chart. Will you please find my mistake?

here doc is my original file WordprocessingDocument  object.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
           WordprocessingDocument.Create("C:\\Sample.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;
            if (mainPart == null)
            {
                mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
                new Document(new Body()).Save(mainPart);
            }

            var chart = mainPart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();
            chart.FeedData(doc.MainDocumentPart.ChartParts.First().GetStream());

            string type = doc.MainDocumentPart.ChartParts.ElementAt(0).EmbeddedPackagePart.ContentType;
            var embdedPkgPart = mainPart.AddEmbeddedPackagePart(type);
            embdedPkgPart.FeedData(doc.MainDocumentPart.ChartParts.ElementAt(0).EmbeddedPackagePart.GetStream());

            string rellId = mainPart.GetIdOfPart(chart);
            string uyo = chart.CreateRelationshipToPart(embdedPkgPart);
            uyo.ToString();

            AddChart(wordprocessingDocument, rellId);
            wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();               
        }
public static void AddChart(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relId)
    {
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Drawing element =
            new Drawing(
              new Inline(
                new Extent()
                {
                    Cx = 5486400,
                    Cy = 3200400
                },

                 new DW.EffectExtent()
                 {
                     LeftEdge = 19050L,
                     TopEdge = 0L,
                     RightEdge = 19050L,
                     BottomEdge = 0L
                 },

                new DocProperties()
                {
                    Id = (UInt32Value)5U,
                    Name = "Chart 5"
                },

                new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Wordprocessing.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                  new GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),

                new Graphic(
                  new GraphicData(
                      new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.ChartReference() { Id = relId }
                  ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" })
              )
              {
                  DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                  DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                  DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                  DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U
              }

        );

        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run(element)));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  public static void WriteChartParts(MainDocumentPart sourcePart, MainDocumentPart destnPart)
    {
        var paras = sourcePart.Document.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Run>();
        var drawingElements = from run in paras
                              where run.Descendants<Drawing>().Count() != 0
                              select run.Descendants<Drawing>().First();

       sourcePart.ChartParts.ForAll(chartPart =>
       {
           destnPart.AddPart<ChartPart>(chartPart, sourcePart.GetIdOfPart(chartPart));
       });

       drawingElements.ForAll(drw =>
       {
           destnPart.Document.Body.Append((drw as OpenXmlElement).Clone() as OpenXmlElement);
       });
       destnPart.Document.Save();
    }
```